# ggvis multiple variable options

Tags: r, ggvis

Let's assume the following data frame

```
mydata = data.frame(
date = seq.Date(from = as.Date('2012-01-01'),to = as.Date('2015-6-01'), 'months'),
name = 'a',
var1 = sample(seq(from = 0, to = 1000, by = 1), size = 42, replace = TRUE),
var2 = sample(seq(from = 0, to = 1000, by = 1), size = 42, replace = TRUE),
var3 = sample(seq(from = 0, to = 1000, by = 1), size = 42, replace = TRUE),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

In my current data set I have more names and I select which ggvis should print with a selection list, and I'd like to know if it is possible to select also which columns represent (currently I am representing only one doing y = ~var1)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution. I turned my data into long format using gather() to convert all my columns into two columns (variable and value), then I applied a filter like this:

```
ggvis(x = ~as.character.Date(date), y = ~value)%>%
  filter(variable %in% eval(input_select(choices = as.character(long.df$var))))
  )%>%
  layer_lines(stroke = ~nombre_centro)
```